# Brake pad change - passat 2011

Tags: tires, dashboard, parking-brake, brake-pad, rear

Implausible signal
Brakes fail 
Very dissapointed[image]

Comment: Is this noted for being from 1 wheel, because it may be an abs sensor fault - depends on the code. If the sensor ring has broken then the system does not get the expected signal.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?